# Return value from Firebase ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I need to check if user already exist in firebase database to return from setOnClickListener. How to get value from ValueEventListener? Perhaps coroutines with runBlocking or else?

```
    registerUserButton.setOnClickListener{

      val dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
      val checkUser: Query = dbReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userNameValue)

      var isUserAlreadyExist:Boolean

    val postListener = object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                    isUserAlreadyExist = true
                else
                    isUserAlreadyExist = false
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
        checkUser.addValueEventListener(postListener)

   if (isUserAlreadyExist){
     return@setOnClickListener
   }
}
```

Earlier I've found this solution

[Return value from valueEventListener java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128909/return-value-from-valueeventlistener-java)

However, it doesn't work how I expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: Firebase APIs are asynchronous. You will need to learn some type of asynchronous programming methods to deal with them.  Don't block the main thread - learn how to deal with them correctly as part of the greater architecture of your app.  If you just want to query for a single value, you should use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) instead of what you show now.